# Does Google Analytics have a "heartbeat" function for long running web applications?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm making a web application that's focused around watching embedded content. I would like the application client to send a "heartbeat" type of signal to GA (Google Analytics) to keep the session going. It seems now that if the visitor watches a video for 5-10 minutes GA assumes that he has left the page and registers an action from the user as a new session.

I'm making this assumption after I got a few hundred people to test the application and the GA Real-time beta registered ~100 people on the page. After a few minutes the numbers started to drop drastically, even though almost all the visitors were still using the application to watch live streams.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would fire an event every 10 minutes with opt_noninteraction set as true.

```
function ga_heartbeat(){
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Heartbeat', 'Heartbeat', '', 0, true]);
  setTimeout(ga_heartbeat, 10*60*1000);
}
ga_heartbeat();
```

You could even set the timeout to be longer. Maybe 25 minutes. It just needs to be shorter than 30min and longer than 10 seconds, otherwise it would be impacted by [hit throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339326/consecutive-ga-hits-being-dropped).

### Update

Note that GA also has a restriction of 500 hits you can send per session/visit. Using something like this can lead you to reaching this limitation more often. After the 500 hits/session limit is reached any extra info sent by the user is just ignored by Google Analytics for that specific session.

Comment: Note:  The option name is 'opt_noninteraction'.  Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en#non-interaction

Comment: `analytics.js` code for Non-interaction events: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events

Answer (score 2):

Google gives you control over the session timeout.  See [here](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/08/update-to-sessions-in-google-analytics.html) and [here](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33073) for more info where it says that the default time is 30 mins of no activity on the site triggers a new session upon the next activity.

You can also set the session timeout time yourself with: `_setSessionCookieTimeout(cookieTimeoutMillis)` as documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSessionCookieTimeout).

I do not see any evidence of any specific support for a heartbeat to prolong a session on a given page.  You could set your own timer and register a new pageview every N minutes whenever content is being watched as that should serve the same purpose.

Comment: To your knowledge, would registering an event called something like "Heartbeat" and running it every minute serve the same purpose? I wouldn't want to bloat my page views with "fake" data. Also I could then set the session cookie timeout to 2 minutes to get accurate data about how long viewers stay on the page. What do you think?

Comment: An event sounds like the best way to keep the session alive, but I don't think you should be sending it every minute when the user isn't doing anything other than sitting on the page (I could see Google objecting to that) and it isn't giving you useful information if the viewer just left their browser parked on that page and left the computer.  If you can somehow tell they are interacting with the page so are still engaged, that's fine, but if you have no idea whether they're still there or just left their computer, then the event won't really work for you either.

Comment: I see your point. However my web application is a bit different than the average blog or company website. I've often opened the application and set it on my second monitor to play a live stream, and I know several of my friends do the same thing, and it can last for many hours. I think it would suck for analytics to report "average visit length" to 15 minutes because it cuts of all the long visits at 30 minutes, and the real average could be an hour or two. How would you recommend solving this issue?

Comment: @Codemonkey - if you don't require any interaction with your site in order to keep it streaming, then there is no way to know the difference between actively listening/viewing and when they've walked away from the computer, but left the browser open.  You will have to solve that to ever have reliable data.  It would be possible to install an event handler that watches for mousemove events anywhere in your window and mark it as still alive (by firing your event every 5-10 mins or so) if a mouse event has occurred in your window.  At least then you know someone is still active on the computer.